# A solution to manage application packaging and updates?

Tags: nuget, updates, packaging, auto-update, squirrel.windows

We have a few Windows apps and a gallery of non-executable assets. All are quite weighty, so we have also an Electron-based app to deliver app/asset updates to our customers as they published. Currently we use an in-house tool, which similar to git compares local and remote repos and downloads/applies on user side patches, not entire packages. The problem is that our tool is outdated and we want to switch to a decent 3rd-party solution (preferably open source). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd-party solutions out there, but all will depend on the kind of application you are building and the way you are packaging and updating. from what you say i cannot know the implications of the app being "old". what do you want to solve?

one starting point would be to checkout [Win sparkle](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle) or [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) both frameworks have their MacOs counterparts.

for a more "web based" solution you can check [electron-release-server](https://github.com/ArekSredzki/electron-release-server)

for the packaging there are many solutions. it's up to the platforms you are targeting. there's no unique solution that covers them all, besides making a Zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have archives (some gigabytes in size) and we need to store them on a update server (securely). Our launcher app (this one on Electron) requests the update server for a new releases available. If any it downloads release to the user install directory. If user has already any older releases, it downloads only the patch and applies it on the older release.  
If it were about electron apps only, I would go happelly with Nucleus (https://github.com/atlassian/nucleus) and app builds made with electron-forge. But its' not. So now I'm looking into NuGet packages and Squirrel